# Is animation in slide presentation distracting from the content?

Tags: content, animation, presentation

Me and my partner are creating a pitch deck that will be used to present o investors for less than 10 minutes. We follow the rule of thumb of having a smart presenter and dumb slides.

But, my partner insists on animating the content of the slides (fade in, zoom out, slide from the top etc..). My position is that such animation is a needless distraction from the content of the slides.

Is there any research? What does UX thinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following the rule of a smart presenter and dumb slides then animation in the content certainly breaks that rule...

Not knowing anything about the contents of the deck, there are some obvious things that I can point out which doesn't require research:

1. Animations takes more time to present, and a 10 minute pitch doesn't give you much time to muck around - besides you also need to allow time for Q & A.
2. Animation is riskier, and more things can go wrong when you try to introduce animation.
3. Animation is harder to maintain and update, and if you are still wanting to change and improve your pitch then you should try to save it until everything is perfected (and nothing is ever perfect).
4. Animation takes more time to prepare... should you spend that time on polishing the content or working out how to do the animation correctly?
5. People (well, their eyes) follow things that move on the screen, so unless you want to specifically draw their attention to something and you have already used highlights somewhere on the same slide, there is no need to animate things.
6. The highest rated slides on slideshare don't seem to have animations in them (at least the ones I have seen), so they don't appear to be necessary if you want a simple, clear (and therefore powerful) presentation.